# Inequalities on Fisher Information / expected second derivative?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, fisher-information, inequality

Under some regularity conditions we can compute fisher information as

$ - \mathbb{E}_{\theta_0} [\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta^2} \ln f(x;\theta_0)]  $

I was wondering if there are some kind of inequality results including the above expecation and an expecation we take under a different true parameter (but not changing the evaluation point of the second derivative), i.e.

$ - \mathbb{E}_{\theta_1} [\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta^2} \ln f(x;\theta_0)] \overset{?}{\leq} \overset{?}{\geq} - \mathbb{E}_{\theta_0} [\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta^2} \ln f(x;\theta_0)]  $

Can we say anything about the relation of these quantities?

(I did a google search already with the obvious keywords, but didn't find anything in this direction)

Edit:

Maybe interesting to note is that in exponential families with natural parametrization, that is $ f(x,\theta) = h(x)g(\theta) exp(\theta  \ T(x))$ we already have that $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta^2} \ln f(x;\theta) = -V_{\theta}[T]$, so there we have equality.

This equality does not hold, however, for the definition as the variance of the score, $ \mathbb{E} [(\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \ln f(x;\theta)) ^2]$.

In this case we have $\mathbb{E}_{\theta_1}[\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \ln f(x;\theta_0)^2] = \mathbb{E}_{\theta_1}[(T - \mathbb{E}_{\theta_0}[T])^2] \geq
\mathbb{E}_{\theta_1}[(T - \mathbb{E}_{\theta_1}[T])^2]  = I(\theta_1)$ ,
such that if $I(\theta_1) > I(\theta_0)$ we get that  $\mathbb{E}_{\theta_1}[\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \ln f(x;\theta_0)^2] > \mathbb{E}_{\theta_0}[\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \ln f(x;\theta_0)^2]$.

I am still interested in more general results, and also it would be interesting how to interpret this.